# Java delimiter reader

Tags: java, delimiter

I have a colon-delimited text file containing structured, grouped data. The `People` group contains people's names followed by their ages, separated by colons. How can I parse the text and group people according to their ages?

The structure is as follows:

```
Group.txt
Age:10:20:30:40:
Group:G1:10:G2:30:G3:20:G4:40:
People:Jack:10:Tom:30:Dick:20:Harry:10:Paul:10:Peter:20:
People:Mary:20:Lance:10:
```

And I want to display something like this:

```
G1 Jack Harry Paul Lance
G2 Dick Peter Marry
G3 Tom
G4
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? If you have absolutely no idea where to start, I suggest taking a look at the String class in javadocs. (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

Comment: i have tried using arraylist. and line.split(":");
but using this method i have to do like line(0), line(1), line(2) etc which is not good because what of there are 100 input within a line?

Comment: Is `Group.txt` in your text file?

Comment: Group.txt is the file name, not included in the text file

Comment: @newbieprogrammer.. What if an age is outside of all the groups?

Comment: FYI: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/155584/156418

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest first creating a `Map` of all the groups with the respective age.

For that you can use a `Regex` that would fetch `alphanumeric` strings on the left, and `digit` on the right of the `colon`, for lines which starts with `Group`.

I suspect that those lines are from your file. So, first of all you need to check whether your line starts with `Group`. Then apply the following regex on that line: -

```
"([A-Za-z0-9]+):(\\d+)"  // Matches `G1:10`, `G2:30`, ...
```

And then add the `group 1` and `group 2` of all the matched string to a `Map<String, Integer>`

Now, for further lines starting with `People`, apply the similar Regex, but with just `alphabetic characters` on the left side of `colon`, and then get the `group` for the particular age from the already created `Map`.

```
"([A-Za-z]+):(\\d+)"  // Matches `John:22`
```

May be this would get you started.

---

**UPDATE :**

Based on your latest edit, I would suggest to create a `Group` class with 3 attributes:

```
class Group {
    private String groupName;
    private int age;
    private List<String> people;
}
```

And instead of creating a `Map<String, Integer>`, create a `Map<Integer, Group>`. Your job will be easier. `Integer` is `age`.

So, as you get a `Person` with a particular `age`, fetch the group object from the `Map` for that `age`, and update the `List<String>` of that `group object` with that person.

Please try it out to see whether you can work it around.

Comment: does this method require hard coding ? because the people name might be different group.txt

Comment: No this does not require hard coding. You can just create a `Map` and use any other file, and get the `People`. And for them get the respective group from the Map.

Comment: @newbieprogrammer.. Good. Do revert if you face any problem.

Comment: @RomanC.. Who are you man? You have posted nonsense comments on 3 of my answers back to back. Seems like you have started word war for some reason I can't understand. And I don't even rememeber I ever talked to you. Any personal reasons, I would certainly like to know.

Answer (score 0):

You could pull apart your lines with a [StringTokenizer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) and then create a "People" class that implements the [Comparable Interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html).

Those should get you started at least.

Answer (score 0):

You can [split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) the string:

```
String[] items = row.split(":");

if (items[0].equals("Age")) {
  // items[1] and onwards consists of Ages
}
if (items[0].equals("Group")) {
  // items[1] and onwards consists of group name/numbers
}
```

and so on

Answer (score 0):

Make a new class that contains a person's information. (This one will work but breaks a bunch of good practices in order to stay brief. Read on POJOs for more details on how to make the attributes private and add accessor methods instead if you'd like. It's a different discussion.

```
public class Person { public String name; public int age; }
```

Then you can use this new class to store people's info into a list that you can access later.

As you iterate through your file, when you find a line that starts with `People:`, then you can parse it with this code:

```
    List<Person> people = new ArrayList<Person>();
    String str = "People:Mary:20:Lance:10:";  // Replace with the line you read from the file
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?:([^:]*):(\\d*):)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
    while(m.find()) {
        for(int i=1; i<=m.groupCount(); i+=2) {
            Person p = new Person();
            p.name = m.group(i);
            p.age = new Integer(m.group(i+1));
            people.add(p);
        }
    }

// At this point, all your people are store into the list.
```

Comment: You don't need that for loop. Your outer while loop is enough. It will give you all the persons with their age. Just print `m.group(1)` and `m.group(2)` in your while loop.

Comment: yeah I guess. I was just trying to make it generic in case more groups are added to the regex.

Comment: @mpvrivat how can I use the variable "age" outside the while loop?

Comment: Edited my answer to help you further. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would break this task into pieces. First, find all the groups:

```
/^Group:(G[0-9]+:[0-9]+)*/
```

Take the first capture group from that line, split each match on `:`, and you'll have the name of each group mapped to the corresponding age.

Next, something similar with people:

```
/^People:([A-Za-z]+:[0-9]+)*/
```

Match, group, and split as you did before, and now you have each person mapped to his or her age. From there, all you have to do is make a bucket for each age group, sort the buckets by age, and put each person in the appropriate bucket.

Comment: how can the group and people join together and sort?